# elastic search by two fields in one object

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new in elastic and have such case when I need to return just records where two fields matched. in my case I have next record in elastic:

```
    {
      "skills" : [
            {
              "id" : 57235399,
              "emsiId" : "KS126QY605N7YVHFYCTW",
              "name" : "PostgreSQL",
              "primary" : true,
            },
            {
              "id" : 57235400,
              "emsiId" : "KS2T0I8XZPQ7P97B9XWV",
              "name" : "Nest js",
              "primary" : false,
            },
      ]
    }
```

I'm using next query

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "skills.name": {
              "query": "Nest",
              "fuzziness": "auto",
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "skills.primary": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

In result in this case I want to return 0 results. I understand why it's working this way, cause it's grabing needed skill first and then filtering by primary that exists in this array as well. So how I can manage this?

Comment: field skills is nested type? Read this [article](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/data-architecture/elasticsearch-nested-field-object-field/#:~:text=Object%20field%20type%20does%20not,otherwise%20use%20the%20object%20type.)

Comment: I've tried to type it as nested, but anyway it didn't work out

Comment: @rabbitbr it worked out with nested and your article. thanks for help!